# Android resource not found exception

Tags: java, android, exception

My application code is as follows,

```
public class Alarm extends MainActivity {

public String str;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //---get the CB message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsCbMessage[] msgs = null;
    str = "";            
    if (bundle != null)  {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsCbMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsCbMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "CB " + msgs[i].getGeographicalScope() + msgs[i].getMessageCode() + msgs[i].getMessageIdentifier() + msgs[i].getUpdateNumber();                     
            str += " :";
            str += "\n";        
        }
        }
        }


EditText user_value;
Button startalarm;


@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.third);

startalarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startalarm);
user_value = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_value);

startalarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{

public void onClick(View arg0)
{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(user_value.length()==0)
{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter a value.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

    SQLiteDatabase aa = openOrCreateDatabase("MLIdata", MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);
    Cursor c = aa.rawQuery("SELECT CblocationName FROM MLITable WHERE CblocationCode = '"+str+"'", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CblocationName"));
    String sas = user_value.getText().toString();
    if(sas==getString(c.getColumnIndex("CblocationName")))
    {
        //here comes the alarm code

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "till here it has executed.",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Notification notification = new     Notification(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder,
        "My Notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    }
}


});
}
   }
```

Though there are no errors, when I run this code it force closes when I press the 'startalarm' button.

My log cat is as follows,

```
11-05 01:31:03.029: W/ResourceType(1554): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
11-05 01:31:03.029: W/dalvikvm(1554): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
11-05 01:31:03.029: E/AndroidRuntime(1554): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 01:31:03.029: E/AndroidRuntime(1554): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:     String resource ID #0x0
11-05 01:31:03.029: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
11-05 01:31:03.029: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:254)
11-05 01:31:03.029: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:183)
11-05 01:31:03.029: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at my.project.mil.Alarm$1.onClick(Alarm.java:68)
11-05 01:31:03.029: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485) 
11-05 01:31:03.029: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-05 01:31:03.029: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-05 01:31:03.029: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-05 01:31:03.029: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-05 01:31:03.029: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-05 01:31:03.029: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 01:31:03.029: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-05 01:31:03.029: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-05 01:31:03.029: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
11-05 01:31:03.029: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've tried all the solutions given in the below link, yet none helped.

[Android, string resource not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676848/android-string-resource-not-found)

Help required,

Thank you.

Comment: What is at line 68 in your onclick?

Comment: @Simon I've just put some string to check if the program is executing till that point or not, changed to 'till here it is working'.

Comment: Just a tip, this code: `if(sas==getString(c.getColumnIndex("CblocationName"))` should be `sas.equals(some string)`, because the variable points to the actual String values.

Comment: @tolgap, Yes, you are right my error is in that statement. I've just deleted that line and executed my program. But, I want to compare string 'sas' with the values of 'CblocationName' column of my database, do you have any idea of how I can achieve this?

Comment: Suufang.  You are missing the point entirely. The reason people ask for the logcat trace is because it tells you *exactly* where the error happens.  Please run your code again now that you have changed it and replace the logcat trace with the new one.  Then find this line, at my.project.mil.Alarm$1.onClick(Alarm.java:68) (java:68 will be a different number) and then tell us what that line is.  Tolgap's comment is correct but that will stop your code from working *correctly*, it is not causing the crash.

Comment: @tolgap thanks for the tip! My app now works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no idea my comment would fix your exception. I will put it as an answer so you can close this question.

Change this line:

```
if(sas==getString(c.getColumnIndex("CblocationName")))
```

to

```
if(sas.equals(getString(c.getColumnIndex("CblocationName"))))
```

Read up on [String comparison](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/12stringcomparison.html) if you don't understand why this should be like this.