# getResource from a Thread

Tags: java, android, xml

I have problems getting a String from the strings.xml file (in the directory res/values).
In my Remote Service, I start a Thread in which I want to access some Strings from strings.xml.

For this, I use :

```
AcquisitionThread(Context context) {
    myServiceContext = context;
}

@Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        myServiceContext.getResources().getString(R.string.base_text_conso);
}
```

I construct the Thread from my Remote Service this way :

```
myAcquisitionThread = new AcquisitionThread(getBaseContext());
```

This is what I read should work, on many subjects.

I don't understand why something as simple as this can fail. Maybe it is because of the Thread created from the Service or something else. Any idea?

Last precision : my Remote Service `extends service` and my Thread `extends thread`

Comment: have you tried it as `myAcquisitionThread = new AcquisitionThread(getApplicationContext());` ?

Comment: I'm confused what the problem is? Do you get an exception? Do you get an empty string?

Comment: Before running, the project, eclipse shows `base_text_conso cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking this post : [Android, string resource not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676848/android-string-resource-not-found) I realised that an `import android.R;` was in my imports. This is an issue you can have when you import too much things without really looking at them.

In order to fix the problem, just delete the `import android.R;` line (you don't need anything else to replace it)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get the `getString(R.string.base_text_conso)` in your Activity and pass it through the intent that you are using to call `startService()` using putExtra() method?

Comment: The problem is not for the service, it is for the Thread. Yes, I could put this string as a parameter when I create the Thread. But if I explained the problem with ONE string, there are many (and the amount is still growing)