# Resources not available in test project

Tags: android, resources

I have a Android test project.  in the resources folder I have strings and colors, but none of the resources are available.  I cannot see any of my strings or colors.  I have cleaned and rebuilt the project without any luck.

To access a resource I am using:

```
String test = context.getResources(R.string.button_text);
```

In this particular case `button_text` cannot be resolved.

[image]

In the strings resource I have four strings

```
 <string name="button_text">Install</string>
 <string name="button_run_unit_tests">Run All Tests</string>
 <string name="Quit">Quit</string>  
 <string name="IsolatedTest">Run Unit Test</string>
```

But I cannot access any from my Java resource files.  What am I missing?

This is what I see (not sure what it's referencing):
[image]

Comment: how are you trying to access your resources?

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6676897/3928341 Also try restarting Eclipse, that fixes a lot of weird errors like this one I get with Android

Comment: @nem  Thanks for the link.  I have cleaned, rebuilt and even rebooted Eclipse.  Still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I missing?

Perhaps you are missing the proper `R` import. Based on your suggested replacements, it would appear that you are importing the `R` from your app. Your strings are not in your app. They are in your test project, which has a different package name. Find the `package` name in your test project's manifest, and try importing *that* `R`.

Note that I have never tried putting resources in a test project, and so while it is possible they would work, I cannot be sure of that.

Comment: It kept importing the default android.R and changing the namespace fixed the reference issue - THANK YOU!

Comment: Thanks. In my case the test project package name had `.test` suffix. And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`GetResources()` gets you an object that allows you to access resources.  To access the resource, you then need to do `get<Type>()` (getString in your case).  So you want to do:

`String test = context.getResources().getString(R.string.button_text);`

Also, you do not strictly need the call to context if you are invoking this in an Activity (since an Activity is a context, you can just do `getResources` directly).

Comment: Either way I cannot see the resource.  Plz see my edit.

Comment: Everything else in your post looks correct to me.  Is your `strings.xml` properly formatted with a header like: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>`?

Comment: Yes, everything is well formed.  The project compiles just fine w/o the resource reference line.

Comment: I'm out of ideas then.  If you hadn't already cleaned your project, I would swear its using a cache for a different project for the tab completion. Do you have multiple projects open in Eclipse?